# Connect to mysql on Amazon EC2 from a remote server - ERROR 2003

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2

cant get it to work. this is what i've done so far:

```
mysql> CREATE USER 'admin'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'xxxxxx';
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'admin'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
mysql> CREATE USER 'admin'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'xxxxxx';
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'admin'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

in AWS Console -> EC2 -> Network & Security -> Security Groups -> quick-start-1 -> Inbound tab -> Choose 'MYSQL' from drop down -> Add Rule -> apply

edit `/etc/my.cnf` and added `bind-address`, then

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysqld restart

sudo /sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --destination-port 3306 -j ACCEPT
sudo service iptables save
```

and finally from my computer:

```
[nir@dhcppc4 ~]$ mysql -h xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -u admin -p 
Enter password: 
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' (113)
```

**EDIT:**
running `netstat -lp | grep mysql` (I dont see port number in the output):

```
tcp        0      0 *:mysql                     *:*                         LISTEN      -                

unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     16003  -                   /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

added in `/etc/my.cnf`

```
port=3306
```

and now `netstat -lp | grep mysql` is

```
tcp        0      0 *:mysql                     *:*                         LISTEN      -                   
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     37757  -                   /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

`/etc/my.cnf` file:

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
port=3306
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
#skip-networking
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

plus i tried to connect through other computer and i could not connect, so i guess its not a problem on the connecting computer

and i got access denied my telnet:

```
[nir@dhcppc4 ~]$ telnet xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 3306
Trying xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx...
telnet: connect to address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: No route to host
```

** i'm also trying to solve it in [amazon ec2 forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=471681&#471681)

Comment: Run `netstat -lp` is mysql correctly listening on 3306?

Comment: Is `skip-networking` enabled in your mysql config?

Comment: Is 3306 port opened in the security group settings of EC2 instance?

Comment: you can see in the question, i did it through AWS console and through the server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SOLVED

the problem:

i have in the iptables this line

```
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

and this line only append the rule to the end of the list so the reject catch it first

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
```

to solve it i needed to put the rule higher in the chain, i.e. use -I switch like this:

```
sudo iptables -I INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
```